# OMNeT++ & INET: Error while using 3rd Party-Tool

Tags: c++, c, simulation, omnet++, inet

I'm using OMNet++ & INET in order to simulate an UDP-Network. 
I changed the `UDPBurst` example a little bit:

- Changed `Router` to an `etherSwitch`
- Using `ThruputMeteringChannel` as connection

Now I change the `ThruputMeteringChannel.cc`, so I can draw charts:

- copping files (`.c` & `.h`) from (http://kuepper.userweb.mwn.de/software.htm)
- Adding import of `chart.h` to `ThruputMeteringChannel.cc`
- adding the Example 1 from the Chart program to the `initialize()` method

When starting the `.ini` file I get an error in the graphical runtime environment:

> Error in module (cModule) UDPBurst.host[0] (id=2) during network
>   setup: Error evaluating parameter 'tcpType': None of the following NED
>   types are available TCP, TCP_IwIP,TCP_NSC,TCP_Node.

In my console is no creating "shared libraries" while building.
But only when I use the `chart.h`

PS: I'm working with Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) on a VM.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the build fails and the library is not built at all. Check the output of the build console for errors, but before building make sure that you run 'make makefiles' from the command line (or use the IDE to build  INET) otherwise the .cc files will not be included in the build and the final linking will fail.